# How to continue filtering beyond BeautifulSoup find_all ResultSet?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Imagine you're trying to parse something like this with `bs4`:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com/arhwth">Title Text</a>
            </th>

            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com/dfdsth">Title Text 2</a>
            </th>

            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com/gsfbf">Title Text 3</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <a href"otherlink.com">Other link to throw you off</a>
</table>
```

Currently I am able to get to a list of all the `th` elements with

```py
html_content = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("parsingwebsite.com").content, "html.parser")

res = html_content.find_all("th", {"attr": "attr"}, class_="title")
```

But I only want the title text inside `<a>`. (ideally `["Title Text", "Title Text 2", "Title Text 3"]`)

Is there a way to continue filtering down by html element or otherwise modify the original query to filter down to the text inside the link, without having to use regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector for selecting `<a>` tags under specific `<th>` tags.

For example `th[attr="attr"].title a` will select all `<a>` tags under `<th>` tags with `attr="attr"` and `class="title"`:

```
txt = '''<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com/arhwth">Title Text</a>
            </th>

            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com/dfdsth">Title Text 2</a>
            </th>

            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com/gsfbf">Title Text 3</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <a href"otherlink.com">Other link to throw you off</a>
</table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print([a.text for a in soup.select('th[attr="attr"].title a')])
```

Prints:

```
['Title Text', 'Title Text 2', 'Title Text 3']
```

---

Or using BeautifulSoup's own API:

```
print( [th.a.text for th in soup.find_all("th", {"attr": "attr"}, class_="title") if th.a] )
```

Comment: thats amazing! I didn't know `bs4` had like lxml support or that you could filter like in the latter example

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<table>    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com">Title Text</a>
            </th>

            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com">Title Text 2</a>
            </th>

            <th attr="attr" class="title">
                <a href="link.com">Title Text 3</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''


html_code = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

a = html_code.find_all('a')
text_a = [i.text for i in a]

print(text_a)
```

Comment: sorry i updated my post because i forgot to include the edge case that there are actually random links on the page